# Assignment expression that sets a dynamically-created enum value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums, expression-trees

I have the following enumeration:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
}
```

This enumeration has been dynamically created using the `TypeBuilder` so there is no compile-time reference to it as a strongly-typed enumeration.

```
// The variable enumBuilder is fully created and ready for use.
var code = Expression.Variable(enumBuilder, "code");
```

I now need to assign `MyEnum.Value2` to the variable `code`.

```
// The following line is supposed to do this: code = MyEnum.Value2;
var assign = Expression.Assign(code, ?????);
```

How do I create the right side of the expression that would evaluate to `MyEnum.Value2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type enumType = enumBuilder.CreateType();
var assign = Expression.Assign(code, Expression.Constant(2, enumType));
```